# How to visually separate dollar sign from variable name in Visual Studio Code?

Tags: php, visual-studio-code, syntax-highlighting

I just switched to Visual Studio Code from Atom and I'm looking for a way to **visually** separate dollar sign from variable name. Such thing was possible in Atom by [editing personal CSS stylesheet](https://flight-manual.atom.io/using-atom/sections/basic-customization/#style-tweaks). After applying [few CSS rules](https://github.com/gakowalski/atom-php-alternative-style/blob/master/style.less) this could be achieved:

[image]

There is no space character between dollar sign and variable name, while editing cursor jumps from dollar to the identifier.

I tried to find a way to achieve something similar in Visual Studio Code but I failed. I know VSC has Developer Tools just like Atom and I've looked into HTML/CSS it generated but I what I saw is that VSC parses PHP code in different way and treats dollar as a part of variable name - unlike Atom which treats dollar sign as a separate entity, a punctation mark.

If visual separation by adding space isn't possible, I'd like to know if it is possible to change the color of the dollar (or dollars in case of [variable-variables](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.variable.php)).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is possible to change the color of `$` or `$$` of php variables as they both have the textmate scope of

```
punctuation.definition.variable.php
```

You can check that with the tool in the Command Palette `Developer: Inspect Editor Tokens and Scopes`.  Once you have activated that tool select `$` or `$$` and it will show you their scopes.

Then you can use that information in the following setting (in your `settings.json`) to change the color or fontStyle of those scopes:

```
"editor.tokenColorCustomizations": {
 
  "textMateRules": [
    {
      "scope": "punctuation.definition.variable.php",
      "settings": {
        "foreground": "#F3873F",   // whatever hex color you want

        "fontStyle": "italic"      // or bold, underline etc. for example
        // intellisense in the `""` (CTRL+Space) will tell what properities are supported
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

You cannot change the spacing of those characters this way and you would have to look for an extension that does it.

Comment: That not only did change the dollar sign color, but also it resulted in separating it into new span element with a new CSS class! To add a space between the dollar and the variable name now I just need to find a way to add one CSS rule. Great, thanks!